# How to echo base64 within CURL?

Tags: linux, curl

I'm trying to make a GET request to a route that requires an Authentication header with a base64-encoded username and password bruce:1234. When I try:

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/users \
     -H "Authorization:Basic `echo -n bruce:1234 | base64`" \
     -H "Accept:application/json"
```

... I get the following output from the CURL command:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /api/users HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.0
> Authorization:Basic YnJ1Y2U6MTIzNA==
> Accept:application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
<
* Closing connection 0
```

However, when I substitute in the base64-encoded value directly, it works:

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/users \
     -H "Authorization:Basic YnJ1Y2U6MTIzNA==" \
     -H "Accept:application/json"

*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /api/users HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.0
> Authorization:Basic YnJ1Y2U6MTIzNA==
> Accept:application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
... [data returned, etc.].
```

What's odd to me is that the initial output of the CURL command (due to the verbose flag -v) is exactly the same for these two approaches, so why then is the first approach failing?

Comment: You can try something like: `A=$(echo -n bruce:1234 | base64) curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/users      -H "Authorization:Basic $A"      -H "Accept:application/json"`

Comment: Sure that base64 program isn't putting an extra newline at the end?

Comment: Thanks Romeo & Shawn -- got it in the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I eventually got to the bottom of what was happening here. I'm using a Mac, and Mac's native base64 does not add any white space to its output. So, in theory, the original syntax would work. However, I had also installed base64 using homebrew, [that version](https://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/base64) was taking precedence, and it *does* add a new line.

Another gotcha is as follows. Based upon [this response](https://superuser.com/a/1225334/978730), I assumed the character being added was the newline char '\n', so I spent ages fiddling around with `... | base64 | tr -d \\n` pipings without any success. Eventually I realized that the brew-installed version was not adding '\n' but '\r' and so I finally got this to work:

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/users \
     -H "Authorization:Basic $(echo -n bruce:1234 | base64 | tr -d \\r)" \
     -H 'Accept:application/json'
```

In summary, you need to be aware of the different behaviors of different base64 builds:

- Native Mac:    base64 adds nothing by default -- no further piping needed.
- Homebrew:      base64 adds '\r' -- you need to pipe it through `tr -d \\r`.
- Linux: base64 (often) adds '\n' -- you need to pipe it through `tr -d \\n`.