# Error parsing JSON while using Github content API with Curl

Tags: json, shell, github, curl, github-api

I am trying to upload a file to Github using Github content API. Referring docs from the official documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents).

As per the docs, the data should be base64 encoded before uploading. I have a `.tar.gz` file which I am converting to base64 using the following method:

```
base64_logs=$(base64 logs.tar.gz)
```

I am using following curl command:

```
content_response=$(curl -v \
  -X PUT \
  -u some-user:$(params.git-token) \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  $content_url \
  -d '{"message": "some message", "content": "'"$base64_logs"'"}')
```

The error message I get is

```
{ "message": "Problems parsing JSON", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise/2.22/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents" } 400
```

I am not sure where I am getting this wrong. I tried to use a hardcoded base64 string, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Needed extra whitespace.

```
    base64_logs=$(base64 logs.tar.gz | tr -d \\n)
```

or you may need to use `\\r` depending on your OS. See below-related answer for more info.

Related answer: [How to echo base64 within CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54065193/how-to-echo-base64-within-curl)